# DIV container stays blank

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I need to run the function `find_optimal_schedule()` every 5 seconds, while each time updating the DIV container `schedule`. Below is my code snippet. The problem is that `alert("Init")` is executed, while `alert("True")` or `alert("False")` are not executed. FireBug shows that `optimize.php` is runned every 5 seconds, but I don't understand why the content of DIV container stays blank all the time.

P.S. The code `gantt.php` works properly, because I tested it in DIV container without the timer and the Gantt chart was displayed correctly. Therefore, I do not provide this code here, because it's not the case.

**scheduler.php**

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){                 
     find_optimal_schedule();
}, 5000);
</script>

<script>
function find_optimal_schedule() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'modules/mod_scheduler/pages.php?page=optimize.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){
            alert("Init");
            if(output.msg === 1){
                alert("True");
                $('#schedule').html(output.html);
            } else {
                alert("False");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div style="width:100%; height:350px; position:relative" id="schedule" class="schedule"></div>
```

**pages.php**

```
<?php
    @session_start();

    @$pag_mod = $_GET['pag_mod'];

    if(!isset($pag_mod))
        $pag_mod = 0;

    if (isset($_GET['pag_mod'])) {
        include 'modules/mod_scheduler/'.$_GET['pag_mod'];
    }
    else {
        include 'modules/mod_scheduler/scheduler.php';
    }
?>
```

**optimize.php**

```
<?php
//  Dispay Gantt chart
$html_code = '<img src="modules/mod_scheduler/gantt.php">';

echo json_encode(array('msg' => 1, 'html' => $html_code)); 
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `output.msg`? It's an if-else, so one of the cases is executed in any case, if it doesn't fail with an error before.

Comment: Hm this is indeed weird. Does this occur in other browsers as well?

Comment: Have you debugged the JSON? Can you post the resulting JSON alone?

Comment: @DaDaDom: If I substitute alert("Init") with alert(output.msg), there is no message at all. I guess the problem is with "pages.php", no?

Comment: What do you get if you `alert(output)` instead of `alert("Init")`? Or, better, `console.log(output)` or `console.dir(output)`?

Comment: @nnnnnn: I get NULL. So, the problem is in pages.php, but I don't understand what's wrong there.

Comment: Try `console.log(output)` before `alert('Init')` to confirm that your server response is correct.

Comment: If `output` is null then it can't have any properties which causes a JS error when evaluating the if condition so execution stops at that point.

Comment: output is null, and therefore referencing output.msg generates an error, and your script stops.

Comment: I tried url: 'modules/mod_scheduler/optimize.php' instead of url: 'modules/mod_scheduler/pages.php?page=optimize.php'. Now it works fine. But what was wrong in pages.php?

Comment: @Gusgus as you mentioned FireBug already, I thought you'd debug with that and not with the `alert(output.msg)`. So, is output null?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you output.msg should be compared with `==` instead of `===`.

```
if(output.msg == 1){
    alert("True");
    $('#schedule').html(output.html);
} else {
    alert("False");
    return false;
}
```

Via nnnnn, it appears that `===` is valid for comparision in javascript; therefore, the only thing I can think of is that output.msg is undefined. Since `===` is not causing the javascript error, output.msg is the only other thing that could be.

Comment: I tried to change to "==". The problem is the same - I see only alert "Init" and that's it.

Comment: Have you checked in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox. The only thing I can think of is that output.msg is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **strict equality** operator (===) instead of **equality**.

This means that the comparison is true if also the **data types** are considered equal, in addition to the values; maybe `output.msg` comes as a string and is not equated to a number. Try == instead.

Comment: But even if it's not evaluating as equal, shouldn't the else case be executed and display the corresponding alert?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I tried it, but the problem is the same. It's not the case here.

Comment: @nnnnnn 's is correct though, you are right, even if that was the case "false" should be displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log(output)
```

to see if output is a valid object. Firebug should show you the entire object with all its properies.